# New console equivalent in the new windows terminal

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, batch, conemu

Migrating from ConEmu to the new Windows Terminal, and looking for behavior similar to [NewConsole](https://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html).

For reference, I'm running a `bat` file containing the following in ConEmu:

```
cmd /c ".\Sample1.bat" -new_console:b:c
cmd /c ".\Sample2.bat" -new_console:b:c
cmd /c ".\Sample3.bat" -new_console:b:c
```

Which will open three separate tabs in ConEmu and execute the different `bat` files.

Can this be replicated in [Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020-09-22, the answer is no. ConEmu must replace or patch cmd.exe to get that syntax to work. I doubt Windows Terminal will ever do such a thing.

However, it looks like the Windows Terminal team is working on a similar functionality: [Add support for wt.exe to run commands in an existing Terminal Window #4472](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/4472). But no scheduled release date, and it will work differently. You would have to execute `WT` with options to open a tab in the existing terminal window and run the `cmd` process.

At this point the only thing that might work for you is a graphical windows scripting utility like [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/).